# Cassandra "Unable to connect to any servers" via Django, while cqlsh works

Tags: python, django, cassandra, stream-framework

I have Cassandra 3.x on my Linux machine.
I try to connect to it with https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework

```
from stream_framework.feeds.cassandra import CassandraFeed
```

I can connect to Cassandra from command line `cqlsh' and using`DBeaver GUI` on port 9042.

When I try to run Django with above import I get this error:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: 
('Unable to connect to any servers', 
{'::1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('::1', 9042, 0, 0)]. 
Last error: Connection refused"), 
'127.0.0.1': error(111, 
"Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. 
Last error: Connection refused")})
```

**EDIT 3**
When all settings are to default values i get also

```
 DriverException('ProtocolError returned from
 server while using explicitly set client protocol_version 2',)})
```

I've looked round for a solution and changed
`/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` to:

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 #from localhost
rpc_port: 9042 #from 9160
listen_address: 127.0.0.1 #from localhost
```

But it hasn't helped.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

**EDIT**
I turned things to defaul settings and `netstat -nat | grep 9042`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56524         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56528         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56522         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56558         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56516         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56514         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56560         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56530         127.0.0.1:9042          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56516         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56514         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56528         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56558         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56524         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56560         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56522         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          127.0.0.1:56530         ESTABLISHED
```

Btw, `nodetool status` returns

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  157.61 KB  256          100.0%            3b13b3f2-968d-4f53-8e9b-1aa4ae271c66  rack1
```

**EDIT 2**
I'm not sure if this is some kind of a clue but when i connect to Cassandra with DBeaver i get only one host listed:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Is it IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Comment: What does `netstat -nat | grep 9042` show?

Comment: @Ivan, i added result of netstat in edit.

Comment: next thing I'd try is to learn which is used by cqlsh and try force your python app to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found problem. Default settings of Stream-Framework for Cassandra Protocol is `2`
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework/blob/master/stream_framework/default_settings.py#L23

after changing it to `4`, the tests and app connect to Cassandra insatnce.

**Edit**

The change is in `settings.py` of main project. Like this:

`CASSANDRA_DRIVER_KWARGS = {
    'protocol_version': 4
}`

Comment: Where did you change this? I am facing a similar issue